# Asymptotic behaviour of recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, biology

> In DNA chain, there are four types of bases: A, C, G, T. Let $g(n)$ be the number of configurations of a DNA chain of length $n$, in which the sequences TT and TG never appear. Write a recurrence for $g(n)$. Determine the asymptotic behavior of the recurrence. Also, prove whether this rate of growth is $o(n^{ n^{1/2}}), \Theta(n^{ n^{1/2}}),$ or $\Omega(n^{ n^{1/2}})$.

My answer:
$g(n)=A(n)+C(n)+G(n)+T(n)$

$g(n)=g(n-1)+g(n-1)+g(n-1)+A(n-1)+C(n-1)$

$g(n)=3g(n-1)+2g(n-2)$

After solving this recurrence, we get

$$\begin{align}
g(n) &= (\frac{(4)(17)^{1/2}+16}{(3)(17)^{1/2}+17})(\frac{3+(17)^{1/2})}{2})^n \\
&+(\frac{(17)^{1/2}-5)}{2(17)^{1/2}})(\frac{3-(17)^{1/2}}{2})^n
\end{align}$$

Therefore when $n$ is large, $(\frac{3-(17)^{1/2})}{2})^n$ become smaller and smaller
So we can write $$g(n) = \Theta((\frac{3+(17)^{1/2})}{2})^n).$$

(Do I determine the asymptotic behavior of the recurrence correctly?)

But I do not know what is the rate of growth, if we take the limit of $\frac{g(n)}{n^{ n^{1/2}}}$,where n tend to infinity, it seems impossible to calculate it. How could I determine the rate of growth?

Comment: Write, for example, `$\Theta$` for $\Theta$; this is what's known as MathJax, a type of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Use `$\frac{a}{b}$` for $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Comment: The exercise is strange because it has a much simpler solution. Namely, note that the total number of configurations is $4^n$ hence $g(n)\leqslant4^n$. Since $4^n=o(n^{\sqrt n})$, you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved the recurrence and found its asymptotic behavior correctly. The growth is $c^n$, where $c=\frac12(3+\sqrt{17})$, and you are asked how this compares with $n^{n^{1/2}}$. The latter is faster: to see this, take logs of both, and note that
$$
(\log c)n=o\Big(n^{1/2}\log n\Big)
$$